# Collapsible Navbar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I've looked around and checked out a few different Bootstrap collapsible menus but haven't been able to figure out why mine isn't collapsing. I have verified that jquery and js are both functional, so that leaves something in this code that wont let it collapse:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <p class="brand"> Collapse </p>
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left " data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i>Basics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../irwtbawd/about.html">About Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../irwtbawd/continuations.html">Continuations</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!--nav collapse -->
            </div> <!--container -->
        </div> <!--Navbar Inner -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace**
`nav-collapse` by `navbar-collapse`

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/133863

**HTML** :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <p class="brand"> Collapse </p>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left " data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i>Basics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../irwtbawd/about.html">About Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../irwtbawd/continuations.html">Continuations</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!--nav collapse -->
            </div> <!--container -->
        </div> <!--Navbar Inner -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a wrong data-target. This should not be a class, but an Id.

It should be something like: `data-parent="#MyPanelId"`.

Give your panel and Id and then add the name in the data-parent field.